# Change color configuration in web application at runtime

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, tapestry

I am developing a web application with `Java + Spring + Hibernate + Tapestry` and I want to allow admin user to change the color configuration of all users registered.

where I store this configuration? In a `.properties` file? In the `database`?

This application will be local, I could force to restart application.

Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: If this application is a web application, are you deploying the application to teh clients with a web container?

Comment: @KennethClark yes, I'll use Apache Tomcat. Thanks for answer, can you read my answer below?

Comment: Storing data in a properties file forces a user to have access to a server. This is a BAD idea. If you do use a properties file, i am assuming you will assigned a colour to a group of users like ADMIN:RED , you system will be required to produce this file or edit it on the fly. Personally is a lot easier to update database entries. PS you will still be required to backup properties files. Linux and Windows files are different and editing them can cause some inconsistancies / corruption : see Evan Knowles comment

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to go with Properties file.

**Advantages in Property file :**

1. No need to access in your database server.(Which is contains valuable data)
2. Anybody can understand and change the settings. (No need to know about SQL)
3. Platform independent.

**Disadvanges in Database :**

1. Need to backup the db. To overcome this problem, Have to maintain the changes by history (It is a best way to revert it back, But again it needs memory).

Comment: The admin "User" should not have access to the database, functionallity should be provided for by the application to change the settings which will give you the functionallity you require. Storing the data in the database gives you versioning (if implemented) and further auditing

Comment: A file might not be platform independent - for example, Windows vs Unix line endings.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
There are a lot of configuration params, and most times read only, but I need this params for all the pages. Only admin user can change this params, but it's a normal user authorized, he don't have database knowledge.
I have a solution but I don't know if this solution is the most efficient: Store a row in database with all the configuration params, and load the most used params in user session?

Answer (score -1):

Where is your user data stored? in database or in a properties file?

Comment: He was asking where he should the configuration - that's the question.

Comment: The question is: "where I store this configuration? In a .properties file? In the database?"